# Xcode Image Catalogs: Image not showing in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcasset

So, the artist sent me a Resources.xcassets folder that I simply dragged into the project. I then jumped to interface builder, added a new UIImageView, assigned an image name from the xcassets, and to my surprise, I couldn't see the images. It shows as a blue question mark.

Notice, that the IB autocomplete is working, and when I run the application, the assets actually show up! But not in interface builder, which makes laying the assets around virtually impossible, especially with the size to fit not working...

**Bug reported: 15733387**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems I am at fault... I created a fresh new XIB, and made sure to select device family 'iPad', and the image is now showing up properly. I didn't think that was the problem because you cannot change the device family after creating the XIB! I looked everywhere for that options, but never found it... Seeing the raw XIB files, you can do this change manually, I guess (Notice where it says ".iPad"):

```
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4514" systemVersion="12F45" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none">
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="4514" systemVersion="12F45" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad" propertyAccessControl="none">
```

---

Yeah, I actually solved it, and the problem is super crazy. The artist had set all the assets as "iPad" assets, so the Contents.json file inside the *.imageset folder was assigning the "ipad" to the images I have. I opened the json file in sublime text, and changed the "ipad" to "universal", and BOOM. I had Xcode open on the side, and the image showed up almost instantly in IB!! Like, wth...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, it was driving me crazy for couple of hours. I had  slightly different situation but the same problem:

I was working on an app for device iPad only, but when I added a new File (User Interface, iOS, "View") that view was not associated with 'targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"' when I screen the source code but - for some reason - only with 'targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch"'.

I changed to 'targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad"' and boom the image was shown in the Interface Builder. The curious thing I never changed the target device, it was always meant to be a iPad-App.

Comment: if change "targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch.iPad", it will return back to "targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" after restart the xcode