# Interface builder shows question mark for PDF images

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, xcode8, asset-catalog

I've been using Single Scale PDF images with no issues.  Now I have slightly different versions of an image for iPad and iPhone.

In the asset catalog I selected the image, selected the Attributes Inspector, checked iPhone and iPad (unchecked Universal).  Then I put the iPad PDF in the iPad square, and the iPhone PDF in the iPhone square.

When I run the app the correct image appears.  But in interface builder, I just get this:

[image]

This happens no matter which device I select under View as.

What is the proper way to setup different images for iPhone / iPad?  Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: These 2 links might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849745/xcode-image-catalogs-image-not-showing-in-interface-builder     &     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2650364/image-not-showing-in-uiimageview-in-interface-builder-iphone

Comment: Well the first link isn't applicable because I don't want Universal, I want iPad and iPhone idioms, and I've provided images for both.  I tried the clean -> build -> restart xcode solution described in the second link; didn't work.  None of the other items in the second link seem to apply / work either.